# Power Bi DAX DateDiff Calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

How do I write a DAX formula to calculate the date difference between two columns. The calculate column should be name OnTime and if true should be Y, if not, N.
The difference should be in minutes. There's a fix target value which is 30 minutes divided by 1440 (number of minutes in a day)

See the formula in excel below

=IF(ISBLANK(F5),"",IF(ABS((F5-E5)<(Targets!$E$4/1440)),"Y","N"))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new **COLUMN** using the following DAX-

```
On-Time? = 
IF(
    ISBLANK('your_table_name'[plan]),
    BLANK(), 
    IF(
        DATEDIFF('your_table_name'[plan],'your_table_name'[actual],MINUTE) < 30/1440,
        "Y",
        "N"
    )
)
```

Sample output will be like-

[image]